# Syntax error in bash script

Tags: bash

On writing few commands at command line, it works, However placing the same in a script file throws error.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
USER=chandan-jay
REPO=test-1
echo "GitHub UserID: $USER"
echo "Repository Name: $REPO"
str={\"name\":\"$REPO\"}
curl_response=($( curl -u "$USER" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d $str ))
echo ${curl_response[@]}
```

when executing above code line after line on shell if works file.
When putting them together in a .sh file it throws syntax error (line number 13 is `curl_response`):

```
__git_create_repo_CLI.sh: 13: git_create_repo_CLI.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected__
```

Comment: Formatting tip: indent each line with four spaces to format a block of code.

Comment: This code works for me, once I changed the username

Comment: Are you sure you're running your script using a Bash interpreter?

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of your script? If not, it might be defaulting to `/bin/sh`, which might not support arrays like that.

Comment: @icktoofay you are right. I tested code with `#!/bin/sh` and I got error but with `#!/bin/bash` it works fine.

Comment: @icktoofay /bin/sh is usually bound to /bin/bash

Comment: @phyrrus9: It's been rather common in my experience that that's not the case.

Comment: Remember that `bash` behaves differently when it detects that it is invoked as `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash` (or, more accurately, when the last component of the file name is `sh` rather than `bash`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That's true, but of the behaviors listed at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode, I don't see which one could be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bash instead of sh while executing the code.
Have a look at this for a better explaination
http://viewsby.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/shell-script-arrays-syntax-error-unexpected/

Answer (score 2):

Set your interpreter to bash, like so :

`#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](https://github.com/hdiwan/test-1) look like what you want? I just ran the script, unchanged with my username, under bash, which is /bin/sh on Mac OS X and that's what I got.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this

```
curl_response=($( curl -u "$USER" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d $str ))
```

to this

```
curl_response=`curl -u "$USER" -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d $str`
```

Hope this helps

Comment: **-1** No. No no no. [No backquotes.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082) Also, this now sets the variable to a scalar rather than an array.